# How do I create a scatterplot matrix of a sliced CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to python and this Pandas stuff. I'm trying to learn machine learning as a hobby more than anything. This is what I have so far.

I can't figure out how to stop the code and put the error I get.

With this code I keep getting this error. How can I fix it?

I'm using Introduction to Statistical Learning and doing the exercises, but instead of using R I'm using Python if that helps

> ```
>   File "college.py", line 12, in <module>
>     pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(data1) 
>   File "/Users//Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_misc.py", line 134, in scatter_matrix
>     **kwargs,
>   File "/Users//Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/misc.py", line 30, in scatter_matrix
>     fig, axes = _subplots(naxes=naxes, figsize=figsize, ax=ax, squeeze=False)
>   File "/Users//Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/tools.py", line 231, in _subplots
>     ax0 = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 1, **subplot_kw)
>   File "/Users//Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1414, in add_subplot
>     a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users//Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 59, in __init__
>     f"num must be 1 <= num <= {rows*cols}, not {num}")
> ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 1
> ```

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv('college.csv', index_col = 0) 

# Summarize Dataset
print(data.describe())

# Plot first 10 columns into scatterplot matrix 
data1 = data.iloc[0:10]
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(data1)```
````

Comment: FYI `data.iloc[0:10]` will read the first 11 columns not 10 as indexing starts at 0 not 1

Comment: Please provide an example csv layout so we know what structure to work with.

Comment: let me know if the answer below help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the kind argument within pandas plot function

```
data1.plot(kind='scatter',x='x_var',y='y_var')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this without seeing your full code. However here is a simple example using similar data that might help.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

data = pd.read_csv('college.csv',index_col = 0) 
data = data[:10]
print(data)
print(data.index)
print(data.columns)

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Private', 'Apps', 'Accept', 'Enroll', 'Top10perc', 'Top25perc','F.Undergrad', 'P.Undergrad', 'Outstate', 'Room.Board', 'Books','Personal', 'PhD', 'Terminal', 'S.F.Ratio', 'perc.alumni', 'Expend','Grad.Rate']);

dataFrame.plot.scatter(x='Apps', y='Expend', title= "Scatter plot between two columns of a multi-column DataFrame");

plot.show(block=True);
```

[Link](https://repl.it/@tanya_gupta/PlayfulStandardNumerator) to fully worked example